# AngularJS - Creating Ad Hoc Web Form from Metadata

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been struggling with a problem that involves building a web form to input answers to questions provided in a JSON resource.

Here's the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/HX11iHdA5kM2yJzDcSTb

This plunk is a prototype for generating a web form based on structured meta data. A sample of the question meta-data is in-lined in the controller. I've assigned it to a questions variable of the model, and provided a second model object called "answers" where I want to bind the data input into the rendered form.

My goal is to add each question to the answers object as a new property. But I'm stuck on getting the data input into the rendered form bound to the model.

The problem is that I am unable to successfully bind the particular question to the ng-model. The problematic area of the code is in the Link function of the *fsQuestionnaireQuestion* directive:

```
var modelLinkId = scope.question.linkId;
var modelAccessor = scope.ngModel + $parse(modelLinkId);

function updateModel() {
  var val = element.value;
  scope.$apply(function(scope) {
    modelAccessor.assign(scope, val);
  });
}

scope.$watch(modelLinkId, function(val) {
  element.value = val;
  });

element.bind('change', updateModel);
```

The form renders fine, but when I input data into any of the form elements, I get back an "undefined is not a function" error.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the second line of this snipped? "var modelAccessor = scope.ngModel + $parse(modelLinkId);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line of your snipped:

```
var modelAccessor = scope.ngModel + $parse(modelLinkId);
```

is concatenating 2 objects, so the result (modelAccessor) will be a string, not the "Model" object that I guess that you were expecting.

I think that you wanted that line to be like this:

```
var modelAccessor = $parse(modelLinkId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That did fix the error, but it doesn't solve the large problem of getting a binding established for the input back to the model. While the change binding works, once the event fires the value for element.value comes back as 'undefined'.